# MYSQL Trigger Update Copy Entire Row

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger to copy an entire row to an audit table on any *UPDATE*.

I have 2 tables

`Frequencies` and `Frequencies_Audit`

This is my trigger.

```
create trigger auditlog 
before update on frequencies
for each row insert into
frequencies_audit select frequencies.*;
```

When I update the record I get Unknown Table `frequencies`.

I don't want to have to enter each field name separately if possible since we are constantly adding columns in the database.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rather than `BEFORE UPDATE`, you can write `AFTER UPDATE` trigger as follow ::

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER auditlog AFTER UPDATE ON frequencies
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO frequencies_audit select * from frequencies where freqId = NEW.freqId;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

freqId is just a name of Id column. Replace it with the name of Id column in your frequencies table.

Comment: Note, you have to override the delimiter if you use the `BEGIN ... END` syntax on triggers

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
create trigger auditlog 
AFTER UPDATE on frequencies
for each row insert into
frequencies_audit select * from frequencies;
```

Because in MYSQL if you wrote `select TableName.*` then it always return an error `Unknown table TableName`.

May be it helps you.

Comment: I get Unknown column 'frequencies' in 'field list'

Comment: No it can't be possible if both table structures are same.please check table structures.

Comment: the table structure is identical.  I did a copy of the table without the records.

Comment: i made this trigger and its working fine DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `auditlog`//
CREATE TRIGGER `auditlog` BEFORE UPDATE ON `questions`
 FOR EACH ROW insert into questions_old select * from questions
//

Comment: just replace your table name in my example code and then execute it.

Comment: That seems to work but copies the entire database not just the row I am working on.   I guess I will have to put a WHERE statement?  To be more specific i want to only copy the row that is being updated.