# Use mysql triggers to backup row after updating events

Tags: mysql, triggers, backup

I found this question [MYSQL Trigger Update Copy Entire Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642456/mysql-trigger-update-copy-entire-row/36117320?noredirect=1#comment59875127_36117320)

Where the suggestion to use the following code answer partially to my personal question to perform a row backup after altering a DB row:

```
 DROP TRIGGER auditlog

 CREATE TRIGGER auditlog AFTER UPDATE ON frequencies

 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  

 INSERT INTO frequencies_audit select * from frequencies where freqId = NEW.freqId;

 END;
```

The problem is that I like to insert additional information to the backuped row so I thought that add variables could do the trick. My question is, is this the right procedure?

```
INSERT INTO frequencies_audit select *, @variable, 'my_value' from frequencies where freqId = NEW.freqId;
```

Comment: What sort of "additional information" do you want to add?

Comment: the backup table has few column further all the same filed of the original table. So with the

`INSERT INTO frequencies_audit select *` I'm able to fill in the backup table the same field from the original one, but with the INSERT query I need to add additional value in the other few field. I don't know if setting up vaiables and format the query in this way `INSERT INTO frequencies_audit select *, @variable, 'my_value' from frequencies where freqId = NEW.freqId;` is the right procedure. I'm also not confident with the `where freqId = NEW.freqId` code does.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I stumbled upon exactly the same question. For me, just adding the missing fields directly like in:

```
INSERT INTO frequencies_audit select *,"insert" as operation from frequencies where id = NEW.id
```

worked fine for me. For more realistic cases, you would have to join.